# Get all elements from class with specific css style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get the first element that has style.fontWeight = 'bold';

Heres what i tried

```
function navigate(input) {
  var array = document.querySelectorAll('.menuulli').style.fontWeight == 'bold';
  console.log(array)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that element has an inline style (i.e. `<div style="font-weight: bold">`) ?

Comment: Yes. So that Javascript looks for all elements in a class that have that style

Comment: Then try this `document.querySelectorAll('.menuulli[style="font-weight: bold;"]')`

Comment: Now when i have this: `var array = document.querySelectorAll('.menuulli[style="font-weight: bold;"]'); console.log(array)`
It just gives me "NodeList []" in the console. And there is an element that has this css property.

Comment: Show me your HTML

Comment: Look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/Konrud/g7vzc9s5/
Works perfect for me.

Comment: Your problem was because JSFiddle uses different Frames so whe you used `document.querySelectorAll('.menuulli[style="font-weight: bold;"]');` it linked to the different frame. Try my example: jsfiddle.net/Konrud/g7vzc9s5

Comment: Thanks @Konrud this worked perfectly for me. I actually had another CSS property and didnt know you had to list all of them. Worked for me. Thanks again!

Comment: By the way in you example (jsfiddle.net/7zfw5gty/1) there are no HTML elements with the inline style

Comment: I've created an answer for this please, kindly, set it as an accepted if it helped you.

Comment: If you want to search for a style attribute that _contains_ a certain style (rather than consisting of only one style) you should use `*=`, that is, search for `.menuulli[style*="font-weight: bold;"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` with the **attribute** selector:

```js
const array = document.querySelectorAll('.menuulli[style="font-weight: bold;"]'); 

console.log(array);
```

If you have a more than one style declaration on your HTML tag. 
For example: `<div class"menuulli" style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">`

Then use this selector:

```js
/// note the asterisk
const arr = document.querySelectorAll('.menuulli[style*="font-weight: bold;"]');
```

Here is a JSFiddle example:  jsfiddle.net/Konrud/g7vzc9s5

Answer (score 2):

Since *bolder*, *bold*, *normal* all maps to their corresponding ***numerical*** values for the weight of the fonts you can try the following way:

```js
function navigate(){
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('.menuulli');
  els = [...els].filter(el => {
    return getComputedStyle(el).fontWeight == "700"
  })[0];
  return els;
}
console.log(navigate());
```

```css
.menuulli{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="menuulli first">1</li>
  <li class="menuulli">2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are the only one realizing that `bold` can actually be internally converted to number, kudos!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the first element by

```js
function navigate(input) {
  var list=[]; 
  var array = document.querySelectorAll('a.js-gps-track');
  array = array.forEach(function(ele){if(ele.style.fontWeight === "bold"){list.push(ele);}});
  console.log(list[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

querySelectorAll returns a NodeList so you cant check for styles on that but you have to check on items.

```
function navigate(input) {

const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.menuulli');
const elemsArray = Array.from(elems);
array = elemsArray.map((ele)=>
ele.style.fontWeight === "bold");
}
```